# Does anyone in the Empire have legal authority to end Clone Dynasty program?

Tags: foundation-2021

In the beginning of *Foundation* TV series, Hari Seldon warned Emperors about Clone Dynasty and instructed them to end this program. At that time, I thought that Emperors had authority to do that. They just weren't willing to do it.

But, the last episode left me speechless. Brother Day (The Prime) who had supreme authority even among Emperors was helpless. Demerzel (who was programmed to follow orders of Emperors) ignored his words and killed an Emperor to protect the Clone Dynasty and then cried later.

How does the system work? Can Clone Dynasty be ended without external brute force?

Comment: You're assuming that it wasn't lawful order... The show is such a mess at this stage that it should be renamed and just mention it's inspiration was the book. I think what happened was Zeroth Law of Robotics in play, but as far as I know, this should be impossible (at least according to books), so it may be explained later. FYI, in books word robot and/or android is no longer used as no one even knows this technology exists. Robots are a myth, children's tale...

Comment: "Clone Dynasty" in the *Foundation* stories?  Sounds like the producers pulled a *Starship Troopers* stunt - kept the names, threw away the story, wrote a new (crummy) story in its place.

Comment: @JRE Yeah, that's completely different from the books, but I liked it. The show presents it very well. A futuristic culture and system designed around it.

Comment: > How does the system work?
I don't think even the writers know at this point...

Comment: @JRE It’s an interesting addition that creates some on-screen emotional and physical conflict to augment the books’ social conflict, which doesn’t work as well on-screen. The core story of the books, though, is still quite recognizable (so far).

Comment: @StephenS Daneel formulated Zeroth law, but only Giskard ever acted on it, once, with fatal consequences. This was because only way to build positronic brain is with Three Laws; it seems to be "cosmic rule" of sorts. It is implied Daneel can function with Zeroth law, but it's doubtful.

Comment: @AcePL I’ve opened a separate question on Demerzel and the Zeroth Law specifically.

Comment: the clone Emperors left me shaking my head. I haven't found a good explaination why they chose to do that. Do these writers think Queen Elizabeth II is a clone? sigh...it had such potential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be ended by Emperors themselves (probably only by Brother Day alone), and it also seems like they can lose power to the **Galactic Council**, but there were only very small references to it:

> Brother Day: *If the Galactic Council discovers our dynastic thread is broken…*
>
> Brother Dawn: *Galactic Council? They'd never know.*
>
> <sub>*Foundation* - S01E10 - "The Leap"</sub>

Also, Demerzel is loyal to the *Cleonic Dynasty above all else*, not the individuals.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I understood the show.

Brother Day has absolute authority. He is Empire and the emperor, and that is it. Dawn and Dusk have authority through Day, but on their own have no power. He could end the genetic dynasty or disband the empire tomorrow.

Demerzel is a robotic entity. She functions on her own, and the laws of the empire don't have any magical effect on her.

In her core programming she has 1 directive, protect the Empire.

So what happens?

In really there is no system in place for Dawn and Dusk to exercise power. Dawn may be a child, but Dusk is an ex emperor with huge political say. They are supposed to be the same person and always agree on everything. The people must see the three of them always agree on everything. In that moment in the throne room things go to chaos. Day and Dusk start a fist fight. If anyone seems them that could be the end of Empire. Demerzel does what is needed to end the fight and save what she must protect, she kills Dawn. It's like taking the toy away from two children who have never learned conflict resolution.

She can do what she does because it is for the good of Empire.

After she does it there is no replications, because Day knows what she did was right. He knows he lost control of the situation, and she saved him without him backing down.

Unrelated I think she is the one responsible for the genetic drift. The end of the clone dynasty is for the good of Empire.

We also know the laws of robotics don't apply to her, and most likely to anything in this universe. We have seen her kill on orders, or her own will